# Lifting function `a → b → c` to `[a] → [b] → [[c]]`

Tags: haskell, nested-lists, applicative, traversable

I would like to have a function

```
foo :: (a → b → c) → [a] → [b] → [[c]]
```

that takes a function `f :: a → b → c` and two lists `xs` and `ys` and returns a grid (i.e. a list of lists) containing the values of `f` applied to every combination of values from `xs` and `ys`.

Example: `foo [1..3] [4..6]` should return

```
[[f 1 4,f 1 5,f 1 6],
 [f 2 4,f 2 5,f 2 6],
 [f 3 4,f 3 5,f 3 6]]
```

My current approach is

```
foo = traverse . flip . traverse . flip
```

This works, but I wonder if there is some other approach or a pre-defined combinator with which this can be done more nicely (or perhaps even composably, so that it can easily be extended to ternary or n-ary functions)

For instance: if I didn't want a grid of results but just a list of results, I could write `f <$> xs <*> ys`, which is concise, uses pre-defined combinators, and generalises to n-ary functions in the obvious way. Is there a similarly concise way of writing my combinator?

Answer (score 7):

This is a job for list comprehensions!

```
foo f xs ys = [ [ f x y | y <- ys ] | x <- xs]
```

Testcase:

```
foo (\x y -> show x ++ " " ++ show y) [1..3] [4..6]
```

yields:

```
[["1 4","1 5","1 6"],["2 4","2 5","2 6"],["3 4","3 5","3 6"]
```

Comment: That works, of course, but it is quite a bit more verbose than what I had in mind. As I said, I was hoping for something simple in a shape similar to `f <$> xs <*> ys`. Besides, this solution does not generalise to arbitrary traversables, does it?

Comment: IMO the perfect readability is a **huge plus** to the generalization / point-free in this case

Comment: It generalizes to arbitrary monads.

Answer (score 4):

> Besides, this solution does not generalise to arbitrary traversables, does it?

It does (and even more): both list comprehensions can be replaced by `fmap`, yielding

```
foo :: (Functor f, Functor g) => (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> g b -> f (g c)
foo f xs ys = fmap (\x -> fmap (\y -> f x y) ys) xs
```

Now, some simplifications:

```
\y -> f x y === f x
fmap (f x) ys === flip fmap ys (f x) === flip fmap ys . f $ x
\x -> flip fmap ys . f $ x === flip fmap ys . f
```

So

```
foo f xs ys = fmap (flip fmap ys . f) xs
```

Comment: Any `Traversable` is a `Functor`. So this solution generalizes to an arbitrary `Traversable`.

Comment: I can't get this to type check. ghci assigns this type: `foo :: (Functor f, Functor f1) => (a -> a1 -> b) -> f a -> f (f1 a1 -> f1 b)`. Any attempt to assign the desired type results in an error part of which is the following `Expected type: f a -> g b -> f (g c)  Actual type: f a -> f (g b -> g c)`

Comment: @MichaelWelch Oops, sorry. Had to completely rewrite it.

Comment: @svenningsson Yes, my point was that it was even more general (except I got it quite wrong and had to fix).